# FCM Message notifications not being received

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am having a curious issue and am looking for guidance and possibly an answer. I have a server which sends messages to mobile devices running my App. There are three situations:

1. The user is in the app and a dialog box pops up upon sending of the message (it's a permissions dialog, allow or deny). App is in the foreground. This is good.
2. The app is open in the background. The user is in another app and receives a notification that the server wants them to do something. Tapping the notification takes them to the App where they can allow or deny. This is also good.
3. The app has been dismissed (iOS -- swiped up and away). No notificatation is displayed on the mobile device. If the user goes into the App the app asks the server if there are any pending notifications and pops the dialog box. This is very bad.

The problem is #3. Why is the notification not displayed. I've been through the documentation which is a miserable experience. I can obviously communicate with FCM because messages are getting through in 2 of the 3 circumstances. This is the message:

```
data = []byte(`{"message":{"token":"`+p.userToken+`","notification":{"title":"Test Title", "body":"Body of the notification"},"data":{"message_body":"This is a noti"}}}
```

which is sent to the URL:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + Project_id + "/messages:send"
```

**** UPDATE **** One insanely important point. The issue only happens with devices running iOS 17.2.1. It works on iOS devices running 16.7 and I believe 17.1 or 17.2 (a new phone purchased a couple of weeks ago but updated today and it stopped working as described in point #3 above. It also works on Android devices. I was so focused on the issue I forgot what we learned today about the versioning. ** UPDATE **

Be gentle. This is my first time using FCM. TIA.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the payload you are sending to FCM? Does it contain a `notification` property or only `data`?  Without a `notification` nothing will happen when your app isn't running.  When your app isn't running iOS displays the message and it seems that you aren't sending anything for iOS to show.

Comment: data = []byte(`{"message":{"token":"`+p.userToken+`","data":{"message_body":"`+p.msg+`","title":"`+p.title+`","user_id":"`+uid+`","code":"`+code+ `"}}}`)    --- The entire message minus some internal fields.

Comment: That makes a ton of sense however. Where would I put the "notification" property in the message.

Comment: [This is the payload spec](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages) - `notification` is a peer property to `data`

Comment: So, I've added the notification object and no difference in results: data = []byte(`{"message":{"token":"`+p.userToken+`","notification":{"title":"`+p.title+`", "body":"`+p.msg+`"},"data":{"message_body":"`+p.msg...